# SQL Server Enable Logging for Certain Error Codes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get alerts when certain database errors occur. For instance, if a table or stored procedure is queried against that no longer exists, I want an alert.

I've tried creating alerts for these error codes (208, 2812) but they never trigger, no doubt due to the fact that there are only a handful of error codes that are logged, [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15).

From sys.messages:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Error | Severity | Event Logged | Description |
| 208 | 16 | No | Invalid object name '%.*ls'. |
| 2812 | 16 | No | Could not find stored procedure '%.*ls'. |

Is there a way to change the event logged status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's a SP to do it, `sp_altermessage`. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-altermessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

`exec SP_ALTERMESSAGE 208, 'WITH_LOG', 'TRUE'`